# insert frame layout inside another frame layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Can i insert two frameLayout inside one frameLayout?
I tried this code and it doesn't work!!!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/details"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal" > 

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/details1"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

          <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/details2"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

When i click on one element i want detail1 to be printed. I guess the detail1 has been created under details so i can't see it?

Can any one help please?

There is what i want:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     Top-level content view for the layout fragment sample.  This version is
     for display when in landscape: we can fit both titles and dialog.
-->

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/titles"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/details"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/titles1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/details1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/details2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I got the good result :)
thanks to every body help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you have width 0px for all, what are you going to see then? And don't use px, use dip. I don't know what you are trying to achieve, anyway

[deleted my answer]

Comment: this can't work: <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/details"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
android:layout_width="match_parent" make my frame layout in all the screen, android:layout_weight="2" will not work

Comment: why don't you draw some sketch and post it here to let us see what you want.

Comment: i have joined to picture to my question

Comment: ha! picture worth a thousand words! I don't know that you want to do that for tablet. I think you want to do something similar to this http://www.curious-creature.org/2011/02/18/android-3-0-animations-demo/ if it is the case I don't think that a single xml layout will do. try that source here http://www.curious-creature.org/2011/02/22/source-code-for-android-3-0-animation-demo/

Comment: yes it will be something like this but without onScrollview, only onClicks so i will use fragments

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you have not completely understood how to use layout_weight. And that you must keep better track of which family (parent and children) of views that are connected to different layout_weights in your design.

I am not completely sure how things are supposed to work but I assume that you want the left menu to be visible all the time and then have more details displayed dynamically depending on what the user chooses. You also want the map to be partly visible all the time?

Have thrown together some code that does the above. Play around with the code and you will probably be able to understand how it works. Let me know if you have problems understanding the code or if I have misunderstood what you want.

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
    >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Menu"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show Details"
            android:onClick="showdetails" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2.0"
    >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/DetailsLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
        >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:text="Details"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

            <!-- This view is only here to prevent textView2 from completly 
                covering the underlying picture -->
            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.0" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**java**

```
package com.test.insertframelayoutinsideanotherframelayout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class InsertframelayoutinsideanotherframelayoutActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout detailsLinearLayout;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        detailsLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.DetailsLinearLayout);
    }

    public void showdetails(View v){
        if (detailsLinearLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
            detailsLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            detailsLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```