# Fit Image in ImageButton in Android

Tags: android, image, android-linearlayout, scale, imagebutton

I have 6 ImageButton in my activity, I set images through my code in them ( not using xml).

I want them to cover 75% of the button area. But where as some images cover less area, some are too big to fit into the imageButton. How to programatically resize and show them?
Below is the screen shot

[image]
below is the xml-file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0sp"     >
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageButton          

            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button_topleft"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0sp"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button_topright"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0sp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button_repeat"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0sp"     
             />

              <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button_next"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0sp"     
             />

    </LinearLayout>    
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button_bottomleft"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0sp"                                 
             />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button_bottomright"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0sp"                  
            />        
    </LinearLayout>        

</LinearLayout>
```

and a snippet of
myClass.java:

```
public void addImageButtons()
    {
        iB_topleft = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_topleft);
        iB_topright = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_topright);
        iB_bottomleft = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_bottomleft);
        iB_bottomright = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_bottomright);
        iB_next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_next);
        iB_repeat = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_repeat);
    }

    public void setImageNextAndRepeat()
    {

    iB_topleft .setImageResource(R.drawable.aa);
        iB_topright.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb);   

    iB_bottomleft.setImageResource(R.drawable.cc);
        iB_bottomright.setImageResource(R.drawable.dd);   

        iB_next.setImageResource(R.drawable.next);
        iB_repeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.repeat);      
    }
```

Comment: have you checked scaling-methods android provides? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Answer (score 460, accepted):

> I want them to cover 75% of the button area.

Use `android:padding="20dp"` (adjust the padding as needed) to control how much the image takes up on the button.

> but where as some images cover less area, some are too big to fit into the imageButton. How to programatically resize and show them?

Use a `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` to have Android scale the images, and `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to have them adjust their bounds due to scaling.

All of these attributes can be set in code on each `ImageButton` at runtime. However, it is much easier to set and preview in xml in my opinion.

Also, **do not** use `sp` for anything other than text size, it is scaled depending on the text size preference the user sets, so your `sp` dimensions will be larger than your intended if the user has a "large" text setting. Use `dp` instead, as it is not scaled by the user's text size preference.

Here's a snippet of what each button should look like:

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_topleft"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

[image: Sample Button]

Comment: @Steven Byle  Sorry for the late responce, but how can i apply the same but for a relative layout?

Comment: For those looking, `ImageButton` methods `setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER)` `setAdjustViewBounds(true)` do this programmatically.

Comment: Also do android:background="@null" to try the default background

Answer (score 39):

I'm using the following code in `xml`

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

Comment: I have a rather "flat" rectangle and this works well for me...one catch though: make sure you use "android:src" instead of "android:background."  +1.

Answer (score 10):

Try to use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in i-Imagebutton xml

Comment: though this worked and scaled, but i wanted that it should cover 75% of the area for better visibility.

Comment: @PowerPC try to use framelayout give heigh and width to 75% and into that frame layout use your imagebutton and set scale type fit to xy

Comment: framelayout for each imagebutton inside linearlayout? can u plz clarify

Comment: @PowerPC I never use this but this link can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946580/insert-frame-layout-inside-another-frame-layout

Comment: @StevenByle I considered both approach, but since I wanted 75% area coverage, your solution worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I'm using `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` with satisfaction.

Answer (score 6):

Refer below link and try to find what you really want:

> ImageView.ScaleType   CENTER Center the image in the view, but perform
>   no scaling.
>
> ImageView.ScaleType   CENTER_CROP Scale the image uniformly (maintain
>   the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height)
>   of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding
>   dimension of the view (minus padding).
>
> ImageView.ScaleType   CENTER_INSIDE Scale the image uniformly (maintain
>   the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height)
>   of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension
>   of the view (minus padding).
>
> ImageView.ScaleType   FIT_CENTER Scale the image using CENTER.
>
> ImageView.ScaleType   FIT_END Scale the image using END.
>
> ImageView.ScaleType   FIT_START Scale the image using START.
>
> ImageView.ScaleType   FIT_XY Scale the image using FILL.
>
> ImageView.ScaleType   MATRIX Scale using the image matrix when drawing.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Answer (score 2):

You can make your ImageButton widget as I did. In my case, I needed a widget with a fixed icon size.
Let's start from custom attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ImageButtonFixedIconSize">
        <attr name="imageButton_icon" format="reference" />
        <attr name="imageButton_iconWidth" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="imageButton_iconHeight" format="dimension" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Widget class is quite simple (the key point is padding calculations in *onLayout* method):

```
class ImageButtonFixedIconSize
@JvmOverloads
constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = android.R.attr.imageButtonStyle
) : ImageButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private lateinit var icon: Drawable

    @Px
    private var iconWidth: Int = 0
    @Px
    private var iconHeight: Int = 0

    init {
        scaleType = ScaleType.FIT_XY
        attrs?.let { retrieveAttributes(it) }
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
        val width = right - left
        val height = bottom - top

        val horizontalPadding = if(width > iconWidth) (width - iconWidth) / 2 else 0
        val verticalPadding = if(height > iconHeight) (height - iconHeight) / 2 else 0

        setPadding(horizontalPadding, verticalPadding, horizontalPadding, verticalPadding)

        setImageDrawable(icon)

        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom)
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private fun retrieveAttributes(attrs: AttributeSet) {
        val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ImageButtonFixedIconSize)

        icon = typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.ImageButtonFixedIconSize_imageButton_icon)!!

        iconWidth = typedArray.getDimension(R.styleable.ImageButtonFixedIconSize_imageButton_iconWidth, 0f).toInt()
        iconHeight = typedArray.getDimension(R.styleable.ImageButtonFixedIconSize_imageButton_iconHeight, 0f).toInt()

        typedArray.recycle()
    }
}
```

And at last you should use your widget like this:

```
<com.syleiman.gingermoney.ui.common.controls.ImageButtonFixedIconSize
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"

    app:imageButton_icon="@drawable/ic_backspace"
    app:imageButton_iconWidth="20dp"
    app:imageButton_iconHeight="15dp"

    android:id="@+id/backspaceButton"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently found out by accident that since you have more control on a ImageView that you can set an onclicklistener for an image
here is a sample of a dynamically created image button

```
private int id;
private bitmap bmp;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams familyimagelayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );

    final ImageView familyimage = new ImageView(this);
            familyimage.setBackground(null);
            familyimage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            familyimage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);
            familyimage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            familyimage.setId(id);
            familyimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //what you want to do put here
                }
            });
```

Comment: It is not a bad idea. I like.

Answer (score -1):

It worked well in my case. First, you download an image and rename it as iconimage, locates it in the drawable folder. You can change the size by setting `android:layout_width` or `android:layout_height`. Finally, we have

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/answercall"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/iconimage"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```