# Android Image Button, icon does not fit the button area

Tags: android

I'am developing an android app, and I have some several image buttons. My question is:
My image button have a size 25dp x 25dp, and the image that I'am using have 75px x 75px, and it becomes like this [image]

and the real image is [image]

Any idea about what is happening ? Is necessary the image have 25px x 25px too ? What is the best way to make it work ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Google is your friend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116393/fit-image-in-imagebutton-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` or `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in your `ImageButton` tag in Xml

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways for you to solve this. Have a look at `android:scaleType` **[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)**. `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` and `android:scaleType="fitXY"` will both work for you.

You can have a look at some samples and how each of them affect the image **[here](http://etcodehome.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html)**