# ImageButton in Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, android, image, xamarin, imagebutton

I am using the Xamarin Studio. I have a problem when I try to use an `ImageButton`. The problem is that whatever image I use it doesn't fit with the button. The image is too big or too small. Even if I try to resize the button, the image doesn't stretch to be at the same size with the button.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of questions to start with - which version of Xam.Android are you using (stable, beta, alpha) and can you post the code you're currently using?

This solution may help you in any case : [Fit Image in ImageButton in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116393/fit-image-in-imagebutton-in-android?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you need the image to stretch use scaleType attribute with fitXY like so:
try different settings from the visual designer to see the effects

```
<ImageButton
    android:src="@android:drawable/someDrawable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```