# How to resize imagebutton in android xamarin?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I am trying to resize(shrink) imagebutton in .xaml file in xamarin android, but i am getting imagbutton being cut in both top and bottom.Can anyone suggest me how could i shrink image to required size without any cut in image.

i am using visual studio 2015 tool to build android in xamarin

below is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="120dip"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
    android:padding="100dip"
    android:src="@drawable/geocursor_pressed" />
```

**EDITED ANSWER**:

```
these extra 3 things should be added

  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"

 By changing padding you can get desired fit of image in button
 Refer Link for more information :
```

[Fit Image in ImageButton in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116393/fit-image-in-imagebutton-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to use `scaleType`.

This [example](http://etcodehome.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html) might be very helpful

And the solution should be `android:scaleType="fitXY"`.

**EDIT**

Because question was edited and it occurs that it is ImageButton, the solution for that is different scaleType and one more option.

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Also padding might be too big.

Comment: if i use scaletype image is getting cutoff,but i need it to scale it to particular size without any cuting.

Comment: Try to add also android:background="@null". fitXY should resize your image to fit in your width and height. And notice that padding might give you different view than you are expecting.

Comment: But still it doesnt work with my hints ? Could you show screenshot ?

Comment: its working, just i have to give padding.Please edit answer to give padding