# Remove whitespace in imagebutton

Tags: android

In my Image Buttons, there is a lot of white space around the source image. Is it possible to remove this space so that the imagebutton just surrounds the source image itself.

[image]

```
<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/story_1"
  android:src="@drawable/my_story"
  style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
  android:layout_width="55dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
  android:scaleType="fitXY"
  android:contentDescription="Add my story" />
```

Comment: Is the white spaces in original image?, I mean like JPG images ,
see this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116393/fit-image-in-imagebutton-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/story_1"
  android:src="@drawable/my_story"
  style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
  android:background="@null"
  android:layout_width="55dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
  android:scaleType="fitXY"
  android:contentDescription="Add my story" />
```

Comment: this works but I can no longer click the button (works like an imageview now)

Comment: have you set onclick listener? and also `background` has nothing to do with click listener, may be button is too small, set height to at least `24dp`

Comment: Yeah my bad. The button was too small. It works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem caused by the image transparency. Try remove the white spaces around the image and make those areas transparent.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the original image you are using doesn't have too much white since you already have the solution in your xml `scaleType="fitXY"` you can try `scaleType="fitCenter"` but your image is already stretched to fit your entire button in the orginal code