# The size of the image in the ImageButton button

Tags: android

There is an ImageButton button

```
<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageButton"
  android:layout_width="24dp"
  android:layout_height="24dp"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:onClick="onClickMenu"
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_point_white" />
```

I upload a 24dp-by-24dp image to it. I increase the width of the button to 48dp, the height remains the same, the picture is also stretched.

How can I make the size of the image in the button always remain unchanged?

Here is the original image of the image in the button

[image]

Set

```
android:layout_width="48dp"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

I got this image
[image]

Another option

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="36dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:orientation="horizontal">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_title_01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/txt_title_01"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
    <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/imageButtonContainer"
      android:layout_width="48dp"
      android:layout_height="24dp"
      android:onClick="onClickMenu">
      <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"                                           
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_point_white" />

     </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It turns out this picture
[image]

Comment: You can add `scaleType` in your `<ImageButton>`

Comment: It didn't help. I set android: scaleType= "center". But the image still stretched in width.

Comment: refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116393/fit-image-in-imagebutton-in-android
padding, viewBoundsAdjusting and scaleType

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if a Button supports that, but what you would typically do is wrap a RelativeLayout around it, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonContainer"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:onClick="onClickMenu">
    
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_point_white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: All the same, the image turns out to be stretched

Comment: @alex Maybe try with android:src, as I have shown here! If it does not work, please upload a screenshot of how it looks using this code!

Comment: I added to the text of the question

Comment: @alex Maybe try android:layout_centerInParent="true" instead of android:layout_gravity="center"